# Write a Query in MySql server that prints a list of employee names who have been employed for less than 10 months having salary>2000

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a SQL query that prints a list of employee names who have been employed for less than 10 months having salary>2000. Sort this result by ascending emp_id.

I tried this but gave me an error stating extract is no longer used.:

```
select * from emp where 
salary>2000 and (months_between(date, hire_date))<=10
order by emp_no asc ;
```

How do I form the query?

Comment: You should add at least a part of the ```emp``` table.

Comment: SQL server doesn't have a months_between function

Comment: On SQL Server you'd likely use `and hire_date >= dateadd(month, - 10, getdate())` though this might depend on how you want to count months.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: # emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date, salary
'10001', '1953-09-02', 'Georgi', 'Facello', 'M', '2020-02-23', '7850.00'
'10002', '1964-06-02', 'Bezalel', 'Simmel', 'F', '2020-02-23', '1756.50'
'10003', '1959-12-03', 'Parto', 'Bamford', 'M', '2020-02-23', '7850.00'
'10004', '1954-05-01', 'Chirstian', 'Koblick', 'M', '2020-04-15', '3475.00'
'10005', '1955-01-21', 'Kyoichi', 'Maliniak', 'M', '2019-12-27', '1756.50'
'10006', '1953-04-20', 'Anneke', 'Preusig', 'F', '2020-02-23', '7850.00'
'10007', '1957-05-23', 'Tzvetan', 'Zielinski', 'F', '2020-02-23', '7850.00'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Emp 
WHERE Salary > 2000
  AND Hire_Date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
ORDER BY emp_no ASC;
```

| Emp_No | Employee_Name | Job | ManagerID | Hire_Date | Salary | Comm | DepartmentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7566 | JONES | MANAGER | 7839 | 2021-04-02 | 2975.00 | *null* | 20 |
| 7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | 2021-05-01 | 2850.00 | *null* | 30 |
| 7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | 2021-06-09 | 2450.00 | *null* | 10 |
| 7788 | SCOTT | ANALYST | 7566 | 2021-07-13 | 3000.00 | *null* | 20 |
| 7839 | KING | PRESIDENT | *null* | 2021-11-17 | 5000.00 | *null* | 10 |
| 7902 | FORD | ANALYST | 7566 | 2021-12-03 | 3000.00 | *null* | 20 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb47da8341127270122b14fce8b021f4)*

Comment: This Query is giving me an error 1582 , says "Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' 0.000 sec"

Comment: Giving me an error of 1582

Comment: @SusmitaArinaDas That error indicates that you're actually using a MySql, not a Microsoft Sql Server.  The Sql has been modified for MySql.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM Employee WHERE Salary > 2000 AND months < 10 ORDER BY employee_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this test on RackerRank on 04-25-2022:

The expected result only includes the name field, if you include any other fields you will get the message  "wrong answer" as a result. All fields in `order by` clause may be in the list of fields, thus the only way I got it was:

```
select main.name from
    (select employee_id, name from employee where salary>2000 and months<10 order by employee_id asc) as main;
```